# How to prove the union bound with Markov's inequality?

Tags: probability

We have events $B_1$, $B_2$, $\dots$, $B_t$. Prove $\Pr\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^t B_i\right) \le \sum_{i=1}^{t}\Pr(B_i)$.

Wikipedia proves by induction and I also understand this inequality intuitively, that is when summing all the events you're computing the overlapped events multiple times. But I'm not sure how to prove this using markov's inequality. Can someone give some insights into how to prove this? Thanks so much!

Comment: Use $X = \sum_{i = 1}^t 1_{B_i}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: take $X = 1_{B_1} + \dots + 1_{B_t}$.  Note that $\bigcup_{i=1}^t B_i = \{X \ge 1\}$, so use Markov's inequality to estimate the probability of the latter event.

Comment: So is X basically just t? I did $P[X \ge 1] \le E[x]/1$ and E[x] is just t if I understood correctly.. So I ended up getting P[x>=1] <= t. But I'm not sure how this proves the union bound... Could you explain a little bit more? Thanks!

Comment: No, $E[X]$ is not $t$.  Think more carefully about what the indicator random variables $1_{B_i}$ are, and what is their expected value.  It's not 1.

Comment: I just wanna thank you again for the comment! So I was able to derive the (seemingly) correct answer from what you said. $E[X] = 1_{B_i}*P(B_i)$, so if you add all t elements together you get the right side bound.
What I'm still confused about: what exactly is $1_B$? I wanna say it's just 1 (which you said isn't true) because if not, X >= 1 wouldn't be true when there's only 1 element in the union.